# Enable cross database ownership chaining

Tags: sql-server-2005

This is on MS SQL Server 2005.

I have a view which includes a subquery on another database at the same MS SQL Server.

As it stands only Domain Admins can access that view so I understand that cross database ownership chaining is needed.

I enabled it on both databases with:

```
ALTER DATABASE xxx SET DB_CHAINING ON;
ALTER DATABASE yyy SET DB_CHAINING ON;
```

Unfortunately That didn't actually work. Is there something else I must do to apply changes or something?

By the way ownership chaining is disabled at the server level.

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: Vote to move to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can I move it myself? how?

Comment: I don't think your reputation will allow you to move the question (I can only vote to move it as part of a "close").  There is nothing stopping you from going to the DBA site, registering there (using the same account as you have for SO) and creating the question there... once you've done that you can voluntarily delete this one